# Will a headless server wait forever at login prompt after boot?

Tags: boot, headless

Ok, I apologize for the extremely noobish question here. I'm trying to wrap my mind around administering a headless Linux server.

As I'm doing the initial setup, I'm managing it via IPMI so I can watch the boot up process, mount install images, etc. However, once the initial setup is done, I plan to administer it over SSH. I have some experience doing that, and it makes sense to me.

I'm just having trouble understanding what happens if the machine needs to reboot, for example. I assume it will boot my OS, reach the `localhost login:` prompt and sit there forever. Will daemons like `sshd` even be initialized before a user logs in? In the event of a reboot will I have to make sure I have IPMI access to login and start these services? This question is so basic I feel kind of ridiculous for posting it, but I can't seem to find any explanation.

Comment: It might help to answer your question if you specify the distribution and init system you use.

Comment: I'm currently running CentOS 7. I'm sorry, I don't really know what you mean by init system. Are we talking systemd, upstart, and the like?

Comment: Yes that's what I mean by init system.

Comment: I know you've already got an answer - but [this link](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linux_startup_process) explains the startup process so may help.  The key is that the process which is asking for a login is just another piece of software started by the init system.  The init system is the one which does all the work bringing everything up.

Comment: Lucas, I believe the default in CentOS is systemd (which I haven't changed). EightBitTony, thanks for the link and explanation, that really helps clear things up for me. I'd be happy to up vote it if you wanted to make it an answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, it'll remain on the login screen indefinitely unless it's set otherwise (I've never seen anything else happen). If you have the sshd configured to start at boot, which I think is almost always the case by default, you shouldn't have to manually start it.